# Inaccessible QPushButton mystery

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a QT application. It has functioning QPushButtons that are connected to slots in my program. I am now trying to add a new button `myNewButton`, but somewhere, somehow it is not being registered.

For an existing, working button `myExistingButton` I have the line:

```
connect(ui->myExistingButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Foo()));
```

I cannot simply add the line:

```
connect(ui->myNewButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Foo()));
```

The compilation error is:

```
class UI::Viewer has no member named 'myNewButton'
```

And QT Creator does not list the button as an autocomplete option for `ui->` (i.e. I haven't simply mis-spelled the name). The records for `myExistingButton` and `myNewButton` are identical apart from coordinates and naming in the ui file. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the generated file `ui_viewer.h` and *then* rebuilding.

Comment: Weird, that shouldn't be necessary. How does your .pro file look like?

Comment: Mark this post as an answer, to help the next ones reading this thread.

Comment: Sometimes, Qt is crazy like that. I have experienced like that before. Whatever I changed in codes never effected the program. I even made comment the whole source file; it is still working. :S
Then I deleted the whole generated files and then rebuilt like him.

Comment: @RedX There's a delay before you can mark your own questions as answered (48 hours I think) but I will. @Frank there's really nothing strange in the .pro file. If it happens again I will investigate further.

Comment: I am getting a similar error, but I have no ui_viewer.h file, removing  the ui_Settings.h and ui_MainWindow.h cause the build to fail with "No rule to make target"

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the widgets parent-property properly?

Either [upon creation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qwidget.html#QWidget), or by [explicitly setting it](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qwidget.html#setParent).

edit: Also note that

- you shouldn't edit ui_-includes directly, use the form-editor instead
- you don't have to do explicit connects for stuff that is hard-declared in your form; again, use the form-editor for this (right click on the button)

Comment: Yes, `Viewer::Viewer(QWidget *parent)`, haven't changed anything there.

Comment: I mean more like this: `ui->myNewButton = new QButton(this); // 'this' is now its parent`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I wasn't editing the ui file directly, just trying to see what was being generated. I'll do my connects in the form editor though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did add a new button to the .ui form and named it `myNewButton`, right? If so, this could be a synchronization issue in Qt Creator. Have you tried saving all and rebuilding (just to make sure the ui compiler is triggered) your app?

Comment: Yes - clean all, rebuild all, still not cooperating.

Answer (score 1):

I see you solved your problem by deleting `ui_viewer.h`. But a cleaner way is to run `qMake` (from the `Build` menu). I always do this when I get errors like yours -- sometimes `Qt Creator` forgets to run `qMake` when it should.

Comment: Thanks. If this happens again I will try your method and change the accepted answer if it works.