# QCreator designer widget inaccessible from program code

Tags: c++, qt, development-environment, qt-creator

Preface: I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1 (based on Qt 4.7.4, 64-bit) on Mac OS X Lion installed via the Qt SDK.

I am working on a project where I have a UI created using the designer in QCreator. I have several widgets working without issue. I created a new QPushButton widget by dragging it from the desiger palette and set some properties in the designer. However, I am unable to access it from the source code using the ui->[widget] convention. I can access every other widget on the form as expected. A search of the site yielded [one similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373743/inaccessible-qpushbutton-mystery), however the solution specified does not work for me.

I've tried:

- Clean, full rebuild
- Re-running qmake
- Restarting QCreator

I have checked the ui element's generated XML and the widget is included and with the correct objectName and properties, yet the source code portion of the designer does not see it.

Comment: try it on other computer / on linux for example

Comment: A shot in the dark but try `#include`ing your ui_*.h file in the .cpp file.

Comment: @MattPhillips The header file was already included.

Comment: In the .cpp file? It can make a difference.  The order of `#includes` can also matter.

Comment: @MattPhillips Yes, in the source file -- "mainwindow.h" first and "ui_mainwindow.h" second.

Comment: Hmmm, I assume you've tried playing around with the order of `#include`s like I suggested.  In that case, in addition to running clean, also go into your project folder and delete the Makefile.  Sometimes this can hang around unexpectedly.  Then qmake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting the current working directory, checking out the latest source from version control, and creating a new project. After further scrutiny, I found that ui_mainwindow.h, which is generated every compile by qmake, had been moved into the source directory instead of the build directory, which must have caused some internal conflict with QCreator where it would not regenerate it and just copy the old one to the build folder. Deleting the file probably would have worked if I had seen it and saved me the time of starting fresh.